# Clicking on my name in the system menu locks my screen

Tags: 14.04

I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature. But since I could not see it mentioned anywhere, I decided to ask here.

In Ubuntu 14.04.1 (not updated), after I've logged on, I click on my name in the Power drop-down below the Lock button, my screen gets locked and I need to re-login.

*Is this normal?*

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I would advise that you get your machine up-to-date as this may be fixed in later updates. If the problem does not go away after applying all upgrades you should file a bug report.

Comment: If your name below the Lock entry in the dropdown menu has a dot tho the left of it, then it is the user name that you are logged in with, and clicking that name in the dropdown menu should lock your screen.

Comment: @Toroidal: Normal behaviour... **To the closers: his screen gets LOCKED, not LOCKED OUT!**

Comment: @Karel, can you approve Toroidal's edit and drop me a note, so that I can edit again before there is *any more* confusion???  ;-) (1 close vote already!)

Comment: @Fabby: Sorry, the locked out thing confused me...

Comment: @Karel: Thanks and done too!  [Sigh]  Some people have no clue that you sometimes have to read in-between the lines...  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to say, but with your title and your question, people are going to assume you *indeed have a bug*, which is not true:

You do not get "locked out"!  Your screen gets "locked". These are two totally different animals and what you get is *absolutely normal behaviour!* (So it's a feature and thank you for telling me, because I never knew I could do this!) **:-)**

"Locked out" means that you *cannot enter your password any more* whereas "locked" means that your screen *asks for a password*!

Comment: Aneesh; no apologies needed.  Next time when you ask a question, put a question in the title.  Not a conclusion, otherwise humans being humans, everyone will jump to the same conclusion!  It takes crazy old madmen like me to see through all the other craziness!  ;-)